# Segmentation fault while sorting structure array made of pointer

Tags: c++, c, dynamic-memory-allocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find a segfault in my C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082749/how-do-i-find-a-segfault-in-my-c-program)

I am getting the segmentation fault while sorting the structure 
Here is my structure

```
 typedef struct
    { 
    char *id; 
    char *timestamp; 
    char *name; 
    char *text;
    }DATA;

DATA *the_array = NULL;
```

I am dynamically allocating the memory using malloc and realloc.
Now I am using bubblesort to sort this structure.
I am using bloodshed c/c++ ide under Windows 7.
Adding the code where I am getting the exception.

```
for(int i =0;i < num_elements;i++)
    {
           if(strcmp("DUP",the_array[i].id)==1)
           for(int j = i+ i; j < num_elements; j++)
                   {
                       if(strcmp("DUP",the_array[j].id)==1){
                       float n1 = strtof(the_array[i].timestamp,NULL);
                       float n2 = strtof(the_array[j].timestamp,NULL);
                       // Exchange the elements
                       if(n1 > n2)
                             {
                                  // Exchange the id
                                  temp_id = (char*)malloc(sizeof(the_array[i].id));
                                  strcpy(temp_id,the_array[i].id);
                                  strcpy(the_array[i].id,the_array[j].id);
                                  strcpy(the_array[j].id,temp_id);

                                  //Exchange the timestamps
                                  temp_timestamp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(the_array[i].timestamp));
                                  strcpy(temp_timestamp,the_array[i].timestamp);
                                  strcpy(the_array[i].timestamp,the_array[j].timestamp);
                                  strcpy(the_array[j].timestamp,temp_timestamp);

                                  //Exchange the username
                                   temp_username = (char*)malloc(sizeof(the_array[i].name));
                                  strcpy(temp_username,the_array[i].name);
                                  strcpy(the_array[i].name,the_array[j].name);
                                  strcpy(the_array[j].name,temp_username);

                                  //Exchange the text
                                  temp_text = (char*)malloc(sizeof(the_array[i].text));
                                  strcpy(temp_text,the_array[i].text);
                                  strcpy(the_array[i].text,the_array[j].text);
                                  strcpy(the_array[j].text,temp_text);



                             }
                             }
                   }
    }
```

Can I do it like this

```
for(int i =0;i < num_elements;i++)
{
       if(strcmp(dup,the_array[i].id)==1)
       for(int j = i+ i; j < num_elements; j++)
               {

                   float n1 = strtof(the_array[i].timestamp,NULL);
                   float n2 = strtof(the_array[j].timestamp,NULL);
                   // Exchange the elements
                   if(n1 < n2)
                         {
                             //Change the pointer locations
                             temp_array1 = &the_array[i];
                             temp_array2 = &the_array[j];

                             temp_array3=temp_array1;
                             temp_array1=temp_array2;
                             temp_array2=temp_array3;


                         }

               }
}
```

Comment: If you post a minimal example of the code demonstrating the problem, some of who are not psychic may be able to help.

Comment: add you code, and please add it with code tag! like a program not a newspaper !

Comment: @AShelly : I have added the code where I am getting the exception , I am getting the exception under windows, so not able to guess the problem

Comment: Are you asking about C++ or C? They are different languages, with different solutions to your problem.

Comment: Please use a debugger to find on which line the segmentation fault occurs. If you do that, you might be able to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Robᵩ : it is more specific to c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copying elements, you are, for example,  `malloc`ing `sizeof(the_array[i].name))`, which is the size of a character pointer.  If the name is longer than 3 bytes, then you are overwriting unallocated memory when you copy into it.  You need to allocate `strlen(the_array[i].name)+1`.  Similarly for other elements.   And even then you have the issue that the name in node X may be shorter than the name in node Y which you are copying into it.  This whole strategy is doomed to failure.

Is there some reason you are just not swapping the nodes?   Or even better doing 
`qsort(list, N, sizeof(DATA), DataTimestampCompare);`

Answer (score 1):

Your code to exchange the out-of-order array element has several problems. Your question is tagged both `C` and `C++` but in `C++` you can simply say:

```
// Exchange the elements
if(n1 > n2)
{
    std::swap(the_array[i], the_array[j]);
}
```

You only need to swap the structs or the pointers they contain. Your existing code doesn't allocate enough memory for the (unnecessary) string copying and has terrible memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you do the allocation and use the array it will be difficult to answer, but most probably you are only allocating memory for the struct and forgetting about the member pointers. You have to allocate memory for them too, or else if you try to access some of them you'll get a seg fault.

`*the_array->name` Will cause a seg fault if you only allocate memory for "the_array", for example. And I'm guessing your sorting algorithm try to access some of the struct's attributes.